# Using "Select" in SharePoint list query

Tags: powershell, select, sharepoint, caml

I have a list with a large number of datapoints.  (130 columns, 31000 items).  I run certain scripts to data-mine and/or update that info.  One trick I use to speed up processing time is to pull the whole list into an array at the beginning.  This allows powershell to query the array instead of going back to the list each time.

In these scripts I'm usually only searching a few of the fields, making it inefficient to pull all 130+ columns I'm hoping looking for a way to limit what fields are being pulled in.

In the below script, everything works fine until I add the "Select" part of the query.  I then get an error of "**Unable to index into an object of type System.Management.Automation.PSObject**".

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

```
$oList = $Web2.Lists["Forecasting data source"]
$aList = $Web.Lists["ArrayTest"]

filter MyFilter {if ($_["CHGTaskRegion"] -eq "Syracuse") {$_}}
$list = $oList.Items | MyFilter | Select ["CHGTaskFacility"],["CHGTicketNumber"]

$list | ForEach-Object {
    $ListItem = $aList.Items.Add()
    $ListItem["Title"] = [string]$_["CHGTaskFacility"]
    $ListItem["Number"] = [string]$_["CHGTicketNumber"]
    $ListItem.Update()
}
```

EDIT:
This is way after the fact but I saw this old post of mine and figured it was worth coming back to.  The proper method isn't actually to pull in the whole list and then search it.  The right way is to simply get just the items you wanted in the first place using a CAML query.  Like so:

```
$spqQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
$spqQuery.Query =  
    "   <Where> 
        <Eq> 
            <FieldRef Name='CHGTaskRegion' /> 
            <Value Type='File'>Syracuse</Value> 
        </Eq> 
    </Where>" 
$spqQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='CHGTaskFacility' /><FieldRef Name='CHGTicketNumber' />" 
$spqQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = $true 
$splListItems = $splList.GetItems($spqQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

> $list = $oList.Items | MyFilter | Select {$*["CHGTaskFacility"]}, {$*["CHGTicketNumber"]}

Add underscore after dollar signs. For some reason _ is not showing up in the code above.

/Pawel

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be :

```
$list = $oList.Items | MyFilter | Select CHGTaskFacility,CHGTicketNumber
```

The way you wrote it, means that you tried to type cast, anything between `[ ]` being the type.
And so it got confused.

CHGTaskFacility and CHGTicketNumber are properties of the $list of objects, and so Select `CHGTaskFacility,CHGTicketNumber` is sufficient for Powershell to select them.

UPDATE:

I think the filter code may be incorrect:

```
filter MyFilter {if ($_."CHGTaskRegion" -eq "Syracuse") {$_}}
```

Comment: I took the brackets and quotes off those column names.  Unfortunately, no difference.  Same error.

$list = $oList.Items | MyFilter  | Select CHGTaskFacility,CHGTicketNumber

Comment: OK, it could be that the filter is the issue, did you try `filter MyFilter {if ($_."CHGTaskRegion" -eq "Syracuse") {$_}}`

Comment: The filter works fine.  As I said in my original post, the whole script works until I add the select statement.